# Does Ubuntu compile all their non-proprietary packages on their repo from source or do they use the dev's pre-compiled binary?

Tags: package-management, packaging

I was just curious to know, does Ubuntu compile all the open-source/non-proprietary packages on their repo or do they just take the finished bins from the dev and stick If it in the repo?

Comment: The second. Proprietary usually means no access to source code, and you can't compile without it.

Comment: I think you may have misread. The second was non-proprietary not proprietary. I guess, it was pointless for me to add it, since open-source is non-proprietary and non-proprietary cannot be classified as so without sharing the source. Ah well. :)

Comment: Well, things can be proprietary while the source is visible, as the licensing may not grant you the rights to do anything with the code if you do have any access to it, which would mean you could not upload it into Ubuntu under such terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developers cannot upload pre-compiled binaries into the Ubuntu archive. All packages in the main Ubuntu archives are built from the source packages.

From the [Ubuntu for Debian Developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/ForDebianDevelopers) wiki page:

> Ubuntu does not permit binary uploads (builds performed by the developer on their own system) for any architecture. All builds are performed in clean chroots by Launchpad, and uploads are source-only (dpkg-buildpackage -S).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that's really good to know. May I ask where you know this info from? I was trying to google it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Well, as a developer, I just knew. But I found a wiki page that mentions it, and updated the answer.